# What are the dualizable objects in the category of Hilbert spaces?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, duality-theorems, monoidal-categories, topological-quantum-field-theory

Let $\mathbf{Hilb}$ be the category of Hilbert spaces and continuous linear maps. Turn it into a symmetric monoidal category using the [tensor product of Hilbert spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product_of_Hilbert_spaces). What are the [dualizable objects](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/dualizable+object#in_a_monoidal_category)?

Comment: Instead of just linking the definitions, it would be nice if you could summarize them in your question, and even better if you could unwrap what they mean in the case of Hilbert spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is well-known that finite-dimensional vector spaces are precisely the dualizable objects in $(\mathbf{Vect}_K,\otimes)$. The same holds here: Finite-dimensional Hilbert spaces are precisely the dualizable objects in $(\mathbf{Hilb},\otimes)$. This is mentioned [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1905.03393v1) without proof, but I assume that you can almost recycle the argument from vector spaces.

Comment: I've seen that statement, but I tried recycling the vector space version, but I couldn't go through with it because I don't completely understand the definition of the tensor product of Hilbert spaces (it has a different universal property than the one in $\mathrm{Vect}_{\mathbb C}$, it has some extra functional analytic conditions).

Comment: Maybe then ask a separate question about what specifically you don't understand about the tensor product of Hilbert spaces. This is a prerequisite for solving this problem here. One important property is $\ell^2(I) \otimes \ell^2(J) = \ell^2(I \times J)$.